# RegEx to detect if a line doesn't end in a semi colon

Tags: regex

I'm trying to run through some code files and find lines that don't end in a semicolon.

I currently have this: `^(?:(?!;).)*$` from a bunch of Googling, and it works just fine.  But now I want to expand on it so it ignores all the whitespace at the start or specific keywords like package or opening and closing braces.

The end goal is to take something like this:

```
package example
{
    public class Example
    {
        var i = 0

        var j = 1;

        // other functions and stuff
    }
}
```

And for the pattern to show me `var i = 0` is missing a semi colon.  That's just an example, the missing semi colon could be anywhere in class.

Any ideas?  I've been fiddling for over an hour but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: "find lines that don't end in a semicolon." - Your regular expression finds lines that don't contain a semicolon anywhere. Which do you want?

Comment: Sorry just what I found with Googling, it's really hard to find examples of regex for finding where stuff doesn't exist.  I'd prefer a line that doesn't end with a semi-colon (not including any newlines or something at the end).

Comment: Ignore the -1 and give my answer a try. It should work, depending on which regex engine you are using. The only possible sticky point would be the .* in the lookbehind. Not every regex engine supports unbounded repetition in a lookaround.

Comment: Lines that end in a non-semicolon are simply `[^;]$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```regex
^\s*(?!package|public|class|//|[{}]).*(?<!;\s*)$
```

When tested in PowerShell:

```
PS> (gc file.txt) -match '^\s*(?!package|public|class|//|[{}]).*(?<!;\s*)$'
        var i = 0 
PS>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a line that doesn't end in a semicolon you can ask for any amount anything `.*` followed by one character that isn't a semicolon `[^;]` followed possibly by some whitespace `\s*` by the end of the line `$`. So you have:

```
.*[^;]\s*$
```

Now if you don't want whitespace at the beginning you need to ask for the beginning of the line `^` followed by any character that isn't whitespace `[^\s]` followed by the regex from earlier:

```
^[^\s].*[^;]\s*$
```

If you don't want it to start with a keyword like `package` or, say, `class`, or whitespace you can ask for a character that isn't any of those three things. The regex that matches any of those three things is `(?:\s|package|class)` and the regex that matches anything except them them is `(?!\s|package|class)`. Note the `!`. So you now have:

```
^(?!\s|package|class).*[^;]\s*$
```

Comment: No dice.  Your first example finds every single line of my code and your second example finds only lines that have zero whitespace before them, which are all my `package x` statements.

Comment: You would like to match the lines that start with whitespace but just not pick up the whitespace?

Comment: Regarding the matching every line, try changing the end to `[^;]\s*$` which checks if there is a semicolon with whitespace (like carriage returns) at the end of the string.

Comment: Just tried your edited example.  Now it's finding all of the curly braces that open and close the package and nothing else.  Doesn't `!\s` say that it'll ignore any lines with whitespace, like tabs?  That's every line except for 3 in all of my class files.

Comment: Just tried your `[^;]\s*$` example.  That finds every single line EXCEPT pure whitespace, so that's a step in the right direction.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I submitted a new answer. edit - there was a problem with it, let me change it

Answer (score 1):

The key to capturing this complicated concept in a regex is to first understand how your regular expression engine/interpreter handles the following concepts:

1. positive lookahead
2. negative lookahead
3. positive lookbehind
4. negative lookbehind

Then you can begin to understand how to capture what you want, but only in such cases where what's ahead and what's behind is exactly as you specify.

```
str.scan(/^\s*(?=\S)(?!package.+\n|public.+\n|\/\/|\{|\})(.+)(?<!;)\s*$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the regular expression line I'm using to highlight lines of Java code that don't end in semicolon and aren't one of the lines in java that aren't supposed to have a semicolon at the end... using vim's regular expression engine.

```
\(.\+[^; ]$\)\(^.*public.*\|.*//.*\|.*interface.*\|.*for.*\|.*class.*\|.*try.*\|^\s*if\s\+.*\|.*private.*\|.*new.*\|.*else.*\|.*while.*\|.*protected.*$\)\@<!
   ^          ^                                                                                                                                           ^
   |          |                                                                                                                 negative lookbehind feature 
   |          |
   |          2.  But not where such matches are preceeded by these keywords
   |
   |
   1. Group of at least some anychar preceeding a missing semicolon
```

Mnemonics for deciphering glyphs:

```
^          beginning of line
.*         Any amount of any char
+          at least one
[^ ... ]   everything but
$          end of line
\( ... \)  group
\|         delimiter
\@<!       negative lookbehind
```

Which roughly translates to:

Find me all lines that don't end in a semicolon and don't have any of the above keywords/expressions to the left of it.  It's not perfect and probably doesn't hold up to obfuscated java, but for simple java programs it highlights the lines that should have semicolons at the end, but don't.

Image showing how this expression is working out for me:

[image]

Helpful link that helped me get the concepts I needed:

https://jbodah.github.io/blog/2016/11/01/positivenegative-lookaheadlookbehind-vim/

Answer (score 0):

For just line that don't end in a semicolon, this is simpler:

```
.*[^;]$
```

If you don't want lines starting with whitespace and ending with semicolon:

```
^[^ ].*[^;]$
```

Comment: The pattern `[^;]$` should suffice to find lines who last character is not a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match lines that possibly begin with whitespace `^\s*`, then don't have a particular set of words, for example `(?!package|class)`, then have anything `.*` but then don't end in a semicolon (or a semicolon with whitespace after it) `[^;]\s*`.

```
^\s*(?!package|class).*?[^;]\s*$
```

Note that I added parentheses around a section of the regex.

Comment: I appreciate all the help.  This is definitely the closest yet, but it's still finding lines that end with semi-colons.  Just to show I'm not trolling you or something: http://i.imgur.com/h8zwi.png

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do now! I simplified it a bit, should be equivalent. I also made a little change because I realise that it can make a whitespace character be a not-a-semicolon and include the semicolon in any character.

Comment: The change I made is to replace `.*` with `.*?` which says "match me enough of anything to match, but no more than you need to". So it won't swallow the semicolon.